# Hover image issue

Tags: html, css, wordpress, woocommerce, hover

I have a link in text on this page, https://melodylakerart.com/product/sun-on-skin-mask-duplicate-1/ which when hovered over produces a pop up image.

As you can see, the text is broken - all the text between "sensitive' and 'off" should be on one line (including the link)

How do I get rid of the weird line breaks?

CSS is:

```css
.hover_img a {
  position: relative;
}

.hover_img a span {
  position: absolute;
  display: none;
  z-index: 99;
}

.hover_img a:hover span {
  display: block;
}

.hover_img a:hover span {
  display: block;
  width: 350px;
}
```

HTML is:

```html
Sensitive ears? Add an 
<div class="hover_img"> 
   <a href="#">adjustable silicone strap
       <span>
           <img src="https://melodylakerart.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/06/Hanwell-Rainbow-Mask-1.jpg" alt="image" height="100" />
       </span>
   </a>
<div>
to take the pressure off
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The addon is doing something strange with the internal div. It wraps the content in a p tag and pushes the div outside. Best to remove it as not needed and move the class name to the a tag (except)..... Change the a to a span because then you wont have the clickable behaviour.

Change the html to:

```
Sensitive ears? Add an <span class="hover_img">adjustable silicone ear protector strap <span><img src="https://melodylakerart.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/06/Mask-extenders-2.jpg" alt="image" height="100"></span></span>to take the pressure off.
```

Modify the Css:

```
span.hover_img { position:relative; color:#f66f61; }
span.hover_img span { position:absolute; display:none; z-index:99; }
span.hover_img:hover span {display: block;width: 350px;}
```

Answer (score 0):

you have some problemes with the HTML tags organisation

try to replace the the full `<div class="hover_img">` with this code

```html
<div class="hover_img">
    <p>
        <span>Sensitive ears? Add an </span>
        <a href="#">adjustable silicone strap
            <span>
                <img src="https://melodylakerart.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/06/Hanwell-Rainbow-Mask-1.jpg" alt="image" height="100" />
            </span>
        </a>
        <span>to take the pressure off</span>
    </p>
    <p class="form-row form-row-wide wc-pao-addon-wrap wc-pao-addon-22252-0-0">
        <label><input type="checkbox" class="wc-pao-addon-field wc-pao-addon-checkbox" name="addon-22252-0[]"
                data-raw-price="1.50" data-price="1.5" data-price-type="quantity_based"
                value="face-mask-strap-extension-loop-ear-protector"
                data-label="Face Mask Strap Extension Loop Ear Protector"> Face Mask Strap Extension Loop Ear Protector
            (+<span class="woocommerce-Price-amount amount"><span
                    class="woocommerce-Price-currencySymbol">£</span>1.50</span>)</label>
    </p>
    <div class="clear"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for this, but i cant edit the add-on related code - this is a woocommerce plugin. I am just adding code to a description field within the plugin : https://snipboard.io/VmqcAE.jpg

Comment: ok, in this case add this to your css file: .hover_img p br { display: none; }